# Flume - Multi agent flow using HTTP source

Tags: flume

I am newbie to flume. Currently I am load testing my step up. I am using HTTP as the source and file system as the type of sink. Now my requirement is to setup a multi agent flow (2 agents). In this I need to inject first flume's source with a HTTP payload and send the data from sink to another similar flume's source and ultimately writing it to a file.

What type of sink should I specify in the conf file of first agent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flume [Avro sink](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#avro-sink) and [Avro source](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#avro-source) are designed specially for such setup. The first agent uses Avro sink configured to send data to the second agent's Avro source (important configuration parameters are `hostname` and `port`).